# preg_match to accept number between range

Tags: php

How I can validate a age feild in php with `preg_match` to only accept number between [18 - 60].

Here is the code I write to accept 2 digit only, but I want to specify a reange of number.

```
if(preg_match("/^\d{2}$/", $_POST["age"]) === 0)
      $errage = '<p class="errText">Age must between 18 -60 digits </p>';
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need regular expression at all:

```
if ($_POST["age"] < 18 || $_POST["age"] > 60) $errage = 'Age must between 18 -60 digits';
```

And just for the information - this is how regex would look like:

```
~^(1[89]|[2345]\d|60)$~
```